# Django-Rest Framework: How Do I exclude current logged in user from dropdown

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to create a Blog API, where Users can make friends by selecting it from Dropdown.
but here the problem is I don't want current logged in user into Dropdown

models.py

```
class Friendship(models.Model):

friend_of= models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friend_of", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friends", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='single-friend', read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Friendship
    fields = ['id', 'url', 'friend_of', 'user']

    validators = [
        UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=Friendship.objects.all(),
            fields=['friend_of', 'user']
        )
    ]
```

views.py

```
class Friend(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = FriendSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    This view should return a list of all the friends
    for the currently authenticated user.
    """
    return Friendship.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Friendship.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exclude(user=self.request.user)
```

You can exclude the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

use exclude instead of filter on queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Friendship.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user)
```